# Hide paypal information from inspect element

Tags: php, jquery, html, paypal, paypal-sandbox

PHP:

I don't want to show PayPal form while submitting,

I mean I want to hide the cart data and price of items from checkout page hidden fields because it can be editable by Inspect Element(Example. Firebug..).

Instead of that I want to show just items and price(Not original PayPal form), and while click on submit redirection page directly take to PayPal.

I don't want in that way. Anyone help on this..?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why don't you save that details in some array or JSON and assign it to that hidden fields while submitting the form.?

Comment: But the JSON or array values also display in Firbug view right..!?

Comment: Yeah, If they set a DOM break point while submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep your basket in the session and then once the user has pressed purchase on your dummy checkout page, go to the next page output the required form fields and use JavaScript to submit the form that way the user shouldn't have time to alter the form.

Comment: Thank you. I already following same process. But I want to minimize that too. Because if the browser javascript disabled by user then it don't work.